# Failover configurations in Log4j2.properties

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to setup the right configurations for `Failover` in `Log4j2.properties` in my `Gradle` project..

These are the configurations:

```
appenders = console, http, failover
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.http.ref = Http

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n 

appender.http.type = Http
appender.http.name = Http
appender.http.url = https://localhost:9200/test/log4j/
appender.http.method = POST
appender.http.layout.type = JsonLayout
appender.http.ignoreExceptions = false

appender.failover.type = Failover
appender.failover.name = Failover
appender.failover.primary = http
appender.failover.appenders = console
```

However, When I run the application, I'm getting this error:

```
2019-12-29 00:28:41,701 main ERROR Failover contains an invalid element or attribute "appenders"
2019-12-29 00:28:41,702 main ERROR At least one failover Appender must be specified
2019-12-29 00:28:41,705 main ERROR Null object returned for Failover in Appenders.
```

I suspect the the error is relared to `Failovers` configurations , I didn't do it correctly because I don't know the right property name for `Failovers AppenderRefs` for `.Properties` format

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the following properties instead.If you are doing it only for failover appender then use below.You need to add appenderRef to a logger but not to an appender.That is the reason you may be getting an error.

```
loggers=failover
logger.failover.name= #FailOverName
logger.failover.level = debug #or your desired logging level
logger.failover.appenderRefs = STDOUT
logger.failover.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: Thanks @Santossh Kumar .. I'll try it and let you know .. However I'm curious to ask you if there is one full example for `log4j2.properties` to help as a reference ? Where I'm struggling with guessing the right syntax for the properties there .. where all the mentioned examples on their website are in `XML` format

Comment: Please refer this: https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/